# Error In ssis Oledb Source

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, oledb, ssis-2008

I am trying to get data from oleDB and load it into Excel. But when I put sql Command in the OleDB Source it is giving me the following error. But the Command works fine in SQl Server.

SQL Statement : Exec ImpGetOrderDefaults_Ins_PatLoc_Site '0001','-1'

### TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio

```
Error at Ins_PatLoc_Sites [OLE DB Source [16]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.".

Error at Ins_PatLoc_Sites [OLE DB Source [16]]: Unable to retrieve column information from the data source. Make sure your target table in the database is available.
```

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0xC020204A (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)
```

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Comment: How can we advice smth to you if you are not showing us your command? Please add the code you tried to execute

Comment: I have added the sql  Statement.

Comment: I ment the statement including 'and', 'where' and 'where' mentioned in error message

Comment: There is no 'AND','WHERE' in the statement. I am running SP mentioned in the Que.

Comment: But if you do not show the statement, I'm unable to help you

Comment: you should check the definition of your sp, and find the statement causing the error

Comment: Or you can use SQL Server Profiler with error events selected. Run the Profiler and click Preview in your dataset. It will try to exec your sp and the error will br catch by Profiler. You'll see the statement causing it

Comment: But as i Mentioned earlier, Statement is Working fine in the SSMS(SQL Server).

Comment: SSMS may use another data provider, and Profiler will show you the error clearly. For example, there is a known issue with ADO, the merge statement executing correctly in SSMS gets the error if executig using ADO: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'MERGE'", just because ADO was is adding smth to merge: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/96550daa-94e4-437a-b09a-466686c35e73/sql-merge-syntax-works-with-win7-sp1-client-but-fails-with-earlier-platforms

Comment: 'set FMTONLY off'; This Command before Exec Statement worked for me.

Comment: So you have answered your own question?

Comment: Yes I have tried and its working. Thanks.